# Python loop breaks entire script

Tags: python

I have just finished my python/praw reddit ''warning'' system, but when I run it, it crashes. I've tried numerous methods to fix this, but it doesn't work. The code below is the loop that is intended to check the input for the keywords "new" and ''execute'', and if found, execute their assigned code. However, I am unsure how to loop this process, as my attempt (you can observe it in the code below) does not appear to function, as the entire script was broken when I tried to implement it. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
while 2 > 1:  
  da_answer = input("Enter here:")  
  a = (69)  
  b = (420)  
  if da_answer == "new":
    user_to_warn = input("What user do you wish to warn?")
    Warnings.append(user_to_warn)
    reddit.redditor(user_to_warn).message('You have recieved a warning from  
    the',moderated_sub,'mod team. If you recieve a set amount of warnings, 
    you will be banned for a moderator-selected amount of days') 
    if da_answer == "execute":    
     are_u_sure = input("Are you sure you want to temporarily ban users with 
     over 3 reports(y/n)?")    
       if are_u_sure == "y":
         #iterate over warnings
         length = len(Warnings) 
         i = 0
     while i < length: 
       count = Warnings.count('i')
       if count > required_for_ban:
         reddit.subreddit(moderated_sub).banned.add(i, duration=ban_length, ban_reason='testing', 
         ban_message='You have been automaticaly banned for recieving a too important quantity of 
         warnings', note='This user was temporarily banned for recieving a too-important quantity of warnings')
         i += 1   input("Command executed.Press enter to continue.")
```

Comment: Your code's syntax is invalid. Would you check it again?

Comment: There's a really long line in there. try breaking that up first

Comment: "Entire script was broken" and "code doesn't work" are very nebulous terms. What exactly happens? Do you get an error? If so, please edit your question to include the full error traceback

Comment: The interpreter window just instatly closes

Comment: @Boseong-Choi The code is not invalid;it uses the PRAW library.If you want to test it yourself,remove the lines that start with "reddit".

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to work on your syntax writing.

You can use [Pylint Online](http://pep8online.com/), just paste there your code and fix your syntax step-by-step:

1. [Paste Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pqN6.png)
2. [Check results of Pylint and fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9WHc.png)